# Git error on git --bare init

Tags: git

I want to create bare git repo on a shared windows drive. I have installed Git-2.14.2.3-64-bit.exe and navigated to the remote shared windows drive on a server, created dir and try `git --bare init`. This failed with permission denied error, but some dirs and files were created, so I can not realize, why only `HEAD.lock` is not able to create. When I try `git --bare init` on my local drive, it works.

Any suggestions?

```
$ mkdir AssistImp.git
$ cd AssistImp.git/
$ ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 ED9204 1049089 0 10 25 09:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 ED9204 1049089 0 10 25 09:46 ../

$ git --bare init
error: Unable to create 'Y:/AssistImp.git/HEAD.lock': Permission denied

$ ls -la
total 9
drwxr-xr-x 1 ED9204 1049089  0 10 25 09:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 ED9204 1049089  0 10 25 09:46 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 ED9204 1049089 73 10 25 09:46 description
drwxr-xr-x 1 ED9204 1049089  0 10 25 09:46 hooks/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ED9204 1049089  0 10 25 09:46 info/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ED9204 1049089  0 10 25 09:46 refs/

$ whoami
ED9204
```

Comment: How exactly are you using git here? This looks like a unix shell, but you're using Windows. There are a lot of subltle differences regarding to files, such as symbolic links, locking semantics, default permissions, user/owner mapping and so on. With a CIFS share, there is a yet another mapping layer.

Comment: I use git bash installed by that instalator, but I tryed this via cmd.exe and result is same.

Comment: In that case, try first opening folder properties on the server and give "Everyone" "All permissions" (recursive) on security tab. Then do the same on "sharing" tab.

Comment: I have administrators rights, but I can not grant these permissions to this folder. Do you really think, that this is main problem? I am owner of that folder and I am running that command with "run as administrator".

Comment: It's not necessarily the main problem, but the first step of elimination. Being administrator on the client does not mean you have full permissions on the server.

Comment: OK, I have my remote home dir on this server, where I can do what I want. I changed rights like you said. Some files and dirs are created, but error: Unable to create 'H:/assist.git/HEAD.lock': Permission denied still persists.

Comment: Maybe I could ask, if someone know who (which user) is creating file HEAD.lock. For me is strange, that some files and dirs are created, but this file can not be created, because of permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found. The problem was caused by the fileserver policy settings. There was a ransomware protection and some filenames extensions were disabled including the `*.lock` file name. This filename extension was allowed in my specific directory and everything works great.